# Is there a way to scroll the ListView by one in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, listview, dart, flutter

Flutter problem of the day:
I've an horizontal ListView with 10 items.
When a user starts to scroll it, I want to scroll one by one.
So if I'm on item 1, by scrolling, I see the item 2, etc.

There is a way to do this with listview in Flutter?

Comment: Use `PageView` instead.

Comment: Thanks , it makes sense